# Blender wont seem to accept bridge from Daz 3D to blender (read below for more details)

Tags: add-on

Here's my problem:
I have installed the bridge from Daz to Blender into my Daz Studio, so the bridge works fine on that platform.
However, when I go into blender and do edit > preferences > addons, I can't seem to find the add on that says "Armature: Daz to blender" (or something like that)
Here's a screenshot:
[image]
As you can see there is no add on in blender that starts with 'Armature'
Do you know what the problem might be? If your confused about my question please let me know and we can talk about it. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably that's a 3rd-party addon so you should contact the addon author. It may just be that it's not been updated to install in the version of Blender that you are using.

Comment: John Eason is right that asking the author is probably the best course of action to get an answer, but I'll just add that questions about third-party add-ons are on-topic according to the meta post https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/are-questions-about-third-party-paid-addons-on-topic